# Adding multiple ip addresses using ioctl

Tags: c, linux

By using strace and ifconfig, I found that I can set the IP address this way:

```
 #include <sys/ioctl.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <net/if.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
     struct ifreq ifr;
     const char * name = "eth1:0";
     int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);

     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);

     ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
     inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.12.0.1", ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data + 2);
     ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr);

     inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.0.0", ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data + 2);
     ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFNETMASK, &ifr);

     ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr);
     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);
     ifr.ifr_flags |= (IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING);

     ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr);

     return 0; 
}
```

Now I want to add multiple ip addresses on eth1:0. eth1:0 is the 'fake' interface created to add more addresses. Man page of ioctl shows to set and get ip address but is it possible to add multiple ip addresses using ioctl? If so how can I add?

Comment: I believe you need one "fake" interface per IPv4 address.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [netdevice(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html)  I'm not sure I would want to rely on `strace` as a howto. Especially if you do not know the level of optimization applied. You may have pieces of the puzzle put together in a way the compiler chose instead of what a prudent programming approach would be.

Comment: Wouldn't the procedure of adding more IP addresses using ifconfig and stracing that help you to find it out, then answer yourself this question?

Comment: ah indeed a good question *because* the way to add multiple addresses to a *single interface* is now `ip address add`, and they do not even show up on ifconfig...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala actually i tried to use system command with "ip addr add 1.1.1.1 dev eth1:0" and it worked but higher the number of ip addresses i want to add, higher the consumed time. I also wanted to avoid delay. If there is any ioctl command which would do it faster, that would be better for me.

Comment: @Galen thank you for your suggestion, I surely will try this

Comment: @Ritu with `ip addr add` you can add them to eth1, no need for subadapters... the problem is that it indeed messages with the kernel using a AF_NETLINK socket... I suggest you look into ip addr source code!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala   this was my code for ip addr add
`sprintf( command, "ip addr add %s dev %s &",carrIPAddress, carrInterface );
system(command);`   this is time consuming if run in a loop for multiple ip adding, that's why finding a better and faster one if possible with ioctl